# SQL Server 2008: nested statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to write a statement to calculate a total of invoice, each invoice as multiple products and price. I got:

```
SELECT SUM((UnitPrice-Discount)*Quantity)
FROM tblOrderDetails 
WHERE OrderID= OrderID 
GROUP BY OrderID ORDER BY OrderID
```

This is working fine, now I need to add the freight from another table (`tblOrder`) and this is where I'm stuck, I did:

```
SELECT OrderID, Freight+
    (SELECT SUM((UnitPrice-Discount)*Quantity)
    FROM tblOrderDetails 
    WHERE OrderID= OrderID 
    GROUP BY OrderID 
    ORDER BY OrderID)
FROM tblOrders
```

But I keep getting the error:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in
>   views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, subqueries, and common table
>   expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is
>   also specified.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It means just what is says :-) General only the *final* result set is guaranteed order in SQL. In this case the `ORDER BY` doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

It means just what is says :-)

The error occurs because only the ordering of the *final* result-set (that which is returned to the client) is guaranteed when using `ORDER BY`. All intermediate result sets are just that -- sets of records -- the order of the items in the set can vary. `ORDER BY` works with `TOP` because it restricts the result-set based on the "view" established by the `ORDER BY` -- however, unless this is a top-level `ORDER BY` it *does not guarantee* the order of the final result set (just that the "correct" TOP records are chosen).

That is,

```
SELECT FOO FROM (
  SELECT TOP 10 FOO FROM X
  ORDER BY FOO ASC) BAR
```

Does not have a guaranteed ordering of records in the final result-set; the FOO values can appear in any order.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT o.OrderID, o.Freight + SUM((d.UnitPrice-d.Discount)*d.Quantity)
FROM tblOrderDetails d
JOIN tblOrders o ON o.OrderId = d.OrderId
GROUP BY o.OrderID, o.Freight
ORDER BY o.OrderID, o.Freight -- Freight avoids a potential re-order
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `ORDER BY OrderID`:

```
SELECT OrderID, Freight+
    (SELECT SUM((UnitPrice-Discount)*Quantity)
    FROM tblOrderDetails 
    WHERE OrderID= OrderID 
    GROUP BY OrderID)
FROM tblOrders
```

It's illegal in sub queries as the error message states (without TOP or FOR XML) and has no utility for what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have that ORDER BY in the subquery.  I'm guessing that you left that in when you were developing that part of the query.  Remove that and you'll be fine.

```
SELECT OrderID, Freight+
    (SELECT SUM((UnitPrice-Discount)*Quantity)
    FROM tblOrderDetails 
    WHERE OrderID= OrderID 
    GROUP BY OrderID)
FROM tblOrders
```